# Multiple Parameters in Full Search Text?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a full text catalog in SQL Server 2014. I want to use that catalog in a stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @FNAME VARCHAR(50) = '"ABHI"', @LNAME VARCHAR(50) ='GUPTA'
```

This query is working properly

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users 
WHERE CONTAINS(*,@FNAME)
```

My question is how can I pass multiple parameters to `Contains`, using an `and` condition between them?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate this variables:

```
DECLARE @search nvarchar(4000),
        @FNAME VARCHAR(50) = 'ABHI', 
        @LNAME VARCHAR(50) = 'GUPTA'

SELECT @search = '"'+@FNAME+'" AND "'+@LNAME+'"'

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE CONTAINS(*,@search)
```

Answer (score 0):

Until someone comes with the chrome-plated solution for having multiple terms in one CONTAINS, you can use two CONTAINS.

```
SELECT fie FROM foo WHERE CONTAINS(*,@fee) and CONTAINS(*,@fum)
```